# Turn the table columns as rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unpivot

I have the table with the following structure. I need to turn columns as rows

```
ID  NAME      2011   2012
1   macbook   2      241
2   macbook   77     214
3   macbook   0      400
4   iphone    442    555
```

```
with tbl as (
 select  1 as id, 'macbook' as name, 2 as "2011", 241 as "2012" from dual union
 select  2 as id, 'macbook' as name, 77 as "2011", 214 as "2012" from dual union
 select  3 as id, 'macbook' as name, 0 as "2011", 400 as "2012" from dual union
 select  4 as id, 'iphone' as name, 442 as "2011", 555 as "2012" from dual
)
select * from tbl
```

I use Oracle database, I tried to solve the issue by using unpivot function but I stacked on this

I expect to get the result like this

```
ID  NAME    DATE    SALES
1   macbook 2011    2
1   macbook 2012    241
2   macbook 2011    77
2   macbook 2012    214
3   macbook 2011    0
3   macbook 2012    400
4   iphone  2011    442
4   iphone  2012    555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This : Using unpivot

```
with tbl as (
 select  1 as id, 'macbook' as name, 2 as "2011", 241 as "2012" from dual union
 select  2 as id, 'macbook' as name, 77 as "2011", 214 as "2012" from dual union
 select  3 as id, 'macbook' as name, 0 as "2011", 400 as "2012" from dual union
 select  4 as id, 'iphone' as name, 442 as "2011", 555 as "2012" from dual
)
select * from tbl
UNPIVOT (SALES FOR "DATE" IN ("2011" AS '2011', "2012" AS '2012'));
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With 2 subqueries, each getting the result for each year and then UNION:

```
select * from (
    select t.id, t.name, '2011' as "date", t."2011" as sales from tbl t  
    union all
    select t.id, t.name, '2012' as "date", t."2012" as sales from tbl t
) t
order by t.id, t.name, t."date"
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a9825524c314f4036a748fd6ffb56e2)

Answer (score 0):

You could just CROSS JOIN the table with the list of dates, and then use DECODE to pull out the relevant yearly sale value in each row.

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    t.name.
    t.dt "date",
    DECODE(t.dt, 2011, t."2011", 2012, t."2012", 0) sales
FROM mytable t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 2011 dt FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 2012 FROM DUAL
) d
ORDER BY 1,2
```